# C# (WPF) Data Table Memory Management (Advice | Guidence)

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-management, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am working with WPF and I have had some issues with an application I've written with memory freeing.
I have looked at a lot of posts and blogs etc and couldn't get rid of the issue.

I decided to write a simple wpf application from scratch to just do a single task.

**PROBLEM**

I want to have multiple data tables and store data to them and then clear them out.
Once the data table has been cleared memory should be cleared also.

The problem is I am finding memory never clears out...

**TEST APPLICATION**

I have a data table in my Main Window and have several buttons.

1. Add Data (loops around 100,000 times and add data to data table, which is an integer and a string)
2. Call .Clear() for data table
3. Set data table to null
4. Report memory
5. Call Garbage Collector

Buttons 2 and 3 have no effect on the memory in the profiler.
I clicked the Add Data 3 or 4 times and it loops through and adds the data as expected and the memory of course goes up.
So it's now at 128MB which is fine.

Next I call the .Clear() and I would expect memory to go back to the memory when the application was loaded which was 73MB.

I waited a few minutes and I could see the garbage collector ran but didn't pick up the data table. I wanted 10 minutes and nothing at all, memory is still holding at 128MB.

I read the Garbage collector should be left alone to do it's own thing and it shouldn't be called however if I call the garbage collector, the memory will deallocate, although I am unsure if it completely goes back to the initial memory usage as when the application started.

**So what am I doing wrong?**

**How should I execute such a task as adding data to a data table, doing something with it and then clearing it out for a new use later on?**

Is my data table being part of the main window causing a reference so the garbage collector won't collect it? If so why does executing GC.Collect partly work?
For example starting the app at 73MB and doing the previous step followed by running GC I get 93MB.
Why do I still have 20MB more and Why did I have to run it manually?

How bad is it calling GC.Collect, is there any other way?

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dt == null)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
        }
        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("number", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("text", typeof(string));
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(i);
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["number"] = i;
            dr["text"] = "hello world";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        GetMemory();
    }
```

I tried to create a property for the data table but it made no difference until I manually called the GC and the memory went to 60MB, which was less than when the application loaded.
I waited 34 minutes before manually pressing the GC button.

Totally confusing any help, direction to learning material or best practices will be most appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap#when-is-a-large-object-collected

Comment: This looks like great documentation, it will take me a while to read through so I can't say it solved the issue but I will give it a read. So far it is definitely something that has the pieces I need. After further playing I clicked the add button until I hit 1GB of memory, I could see the GC actually collected "some" of the memory but to me that seems rubbish? Why would I want my memory looking like it's 86% used. Also if I clear the DataTable and set it to null and Run the GC it goes down to 86MB which is brilliant but I'm not supposed to call the GC. I need to figure that part out.